# Unwanted Space Between Multiple Children of Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, spacing

I am having a problem removing space between the expanded widgets which are inside a column this is my code for up to 4 expanded widgets there are 3 more i have tried many things it still doesn't work.

```
class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const XylophoneApp({super.key});
  void playsound(int num) {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(AssetSource('note$num.wav'));
  }

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playsound(1);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playsound(2);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playsound(3);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I am getting[this is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKB7f.png)

I want [this is the output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OaPK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextButton` reason for  the margin of the between on your elements. You could use `Inkwell` instead of `TextButton` to remove the gap between the `Column` widgets of your design. Thus you can get rid of problems in this way.

```
class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const XylophoneApp({super.key});
  void playsound(int num) {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(AssetSource('note$num.wav'));
  }

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Inkwell(
                onTap: () {
                  playsound(1);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Inkwell(
                onTap: () {
                  playsound(2);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Inkwell(
                onTap: () {
                  playsound(3);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
           
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The space in between appearing in your output is the padding/margin for `TextButton` widget.

I am not sure why you are using `TextButton`,however to make a `Container` tappable you could user either `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` as below:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                   playsound(1);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                   playsound(2);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                   playsound(3);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

**Output:**

[image]